# C#: Variable changes value while processing

Tags: c#, .net

My variable changes the value while processing. Here's my code.

```
private string[] rawLayer;
private string[] lastRawLayer;

public bool getDisplayMessage(string message)
{
    lastRawLayer = rawLayer;

    rawLayer[0] = "1";

    Console.WriteLine(lastRawLayer[0]); //Output = "1"

    return true;
}
```

Why is my Output "1"?

Comment: Because array is a pointer - or another way, array's name is the pointer to the first element of an array. `lastRawLayer` and `rawLayer` are pointing to the same address in memory, so when you change one, the secons will still point to the same thing.

Comment: Because of your first line *lastRawLayer = rawLayer;* the *lastRawLayer*  and *rawLayer* as essentially the same arrays.

Comment: Because `string[]` variables are actually *references* to an array. Looking for a duplicate, I'm sure there must be one here on SO... Oh, and +1, because it's actually a good (although basic) question with a concrete example.

Comment: from the code you have you should be getting null reference exception

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: We don't know the state of the fields at the time getDisplayMessage is called.

Comment: @Heinzi I meant given this code, assuming their state doesn't change after declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling `lastRawLayer = rawLayer;` you simply add a new reference to the array `rawLayer` instead of creating a new array. Thus every change done to `rawLAyer` is reflected within `lastRawLayer` and vice versa. If you want to make a deep copy of your array you have to re-create it:

```
lastRawLayer = rawLayer.ToArray();
```

Alternativly use [`Array.CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/06x742cw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
rawLayer.CopyTo(lastRawLayer, 0);
```

Which will copy every element of `rawLayer` to the second array. However if you have some custom objects stored within your array you have to re-create those objects also if you want to avoid that a change of the instance at index zero for example is reflected in both arrays. So the following would still be true:

```
Person[] arr1 = new [] { new Person { Name = "Tim" } }
Person[] arr2 = new Person[arr.Length];
arr1.CopyTo(arr2);
arr1[0].Name = "Hans";    // this changes the value for all references to "Tim"
Console.WriteLine(arr2[0].Name);
```

The code above would print "Hans" instead of "Tim" because although you have different **arrays** those arrays reference the same **instances** of `Person`.

Comment: Do I have to initialize `lastRawLayer`?

Comment: See my edit to see how to use CopyTo.

Comment: Great Answer! Thanks!

Comment: @Wavum, yes, you need to instantiate the array lastRawLayer otherwise you will get exception "Object Reference not set to instance of object"

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the same reference to variable lastRawLayer.

```
lastRawLayer = rawLayer;
```

This means whatever object the variable rawLayer is pointing, the same object will be pointed by lastRawLayer. So when you access object using reference variable lastRawLayer, it has same object in the memory and that why you are getting output "1".